# C# Can't access inherited protected variable from Generic class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

First time poster...

New to C# and Generics and I have been experimenting by creating a simple series of Object Tables for read-only data entries. 
On my Generic Insert routine I increment a static Id variable to ensure it is always unique. To try and prevent it being modified I set it to protected but the Generic class which then throws a compile error stating that Id can't be accessed.

I am struggling to find out why exactly as I thought "where T : DBEntity" would allow this.

Thanks in advance:

```
public class DBEntity
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
}

public class Table<T> where T : DBEntity
{

    static int _id = 0;
    private readonly List<T> _set = new List<T>();

    public IEnumerable<T> Set() { return _set; }

    public void Insert(T item)
    {
        _id++;
        item.Id = _id; //when set to protected it is inaccessible
        _set.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Table<T> not inherit the DBEntity class, so Id can't be accessed.

Comment: Table<T> doesn't but T will, right? If I leave it as public it can access Id

Comment: But T is just a generic parameter. Using T from Table<T> is not a inheritance. You can use "internal set" to restrict assigment to current assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're protecting the ID, so you can't set it. It's honestly as simple as that.

Also doing a generic of Table, and tying the generic to a concrete class buys you nothing. Consider an interface instead.

You could fix your issue as the following:

```
public interface IDatabaseItem
{
     int? Id { get; }
     SetID(int value);
}

public class DBEntity : IDatabaseItem
{
    public int? Id { get; private set; }


    public void SetID(int value)
    {
        if (Id == null)
        {
            Id = value;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot set assigned Id; can only set Id when it is not assgined.");
        }
    }
}

public class Table<T> where T : IDatabaseItem
{

    static int _id = 0;
    private readonly List<T> _set = new List<T>();

    public IEnumerable<T> Set() { return _set; }

    public void Insert(T item)
    {
        if (item.Id == null)
        {
            _id++;
            item.SetID(_id);
            _set.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            //Handle this case. Something else set the ID, yet you're trying to insert it. This would, with your code, imply a bug.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have `SetID` in your interface.

Comment: Thanks... I'm obviously still misunderstanding something as I assumed that "where T : DBEntity" meant that it new that whatever T was it inherited DBEntity and therefore had access to Id. Guess I need to do more reading! :)

Comment: No worries, @LucaTImp! Interfaces are what you want (they're better than  deriving from concrete classes), but make sure to keep them small, and behavior defined; massive interfaces or interfaces that only apply to a single concrete class can get you in trouble down the road.

Comment: So given your changes would you consider that a valid usage of Generic? The idea would then to add tables for Pupils, Teachers, Class rooms... I'm sure you get it. :) Again, this is only testing my understanding, or rather lack of!

Comment: This seems perfectly fine to me. "class Pupil : IDatabaseItem", "class Teacher : IDatabaseItem", etc, would be safe as IDatabaseItem only promises a field of ID, which is a very small safe scope for an interface.

Comment: *"Interfaces are what you want (they're better than deriving from concrete classes)"* And this is because...? This is absolutely opinion based statement w/o any prove.

Comment: @IvanStoev Sure this is opinion, but it's not just mine and is one widely accepted. It's not a rule, but it's a strong guideline. SOLID principles are widely accepted by the coding community.

Comment: Widely accepted or not - that's just another opinion. The point is, you can't say "this is better" simply because that's not true. The OP approach is just fine. All he needed was to let the `Id` setter public. I don't see how your suggestion is better since it is providing a public setter, just in a different way.

Comment: Agreed on the public setter being valid. I did the one-time-set ID because OP seemed to be wanting to protect it. This way he can enforce some logic around it; he wants to only set it once, but he can't protect it via a constructor/readonly, so this was just a way for him to protect it. Although the setting of the variable has nothing to do with interfaces; the interface was for the generic Table<T>.